# csv file return specific rows (java/swing)

Tags: java, swing, csv

I have a problem that filter the csv file. In my GUI user choose his test case name by depending on the test case name I want to eliminate the csv file. For example I choose from JTable case1 and case2 and I store them in a string list [case1,case2] and how can I get the only rows that have test name case1 and case2.

I tried to read csv file and create jtable and action listener to store the choosen test cases as string in the list and they worked. However; filtering part I have really no idea?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: And you tried what exactly? What is your problem

Comment: @redFIVE I dont know how I can filter the csv file.

Comment: I dont want to specific codes, I am a beginner for Java... I just want some tipps. Minus minus perfekt..

Comment: You don't filter the csv file. Instead load all the data into a JTable. Then you filter the table. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get name of test cases from somewhere and store it in a list as follow:

```
List<String> cases = Arrays.asList("case1", "case9");
```

Then you want to read a file that contains many cases including `case1` and `case9` and you want to select only those lines. If correct, then assuming that you have the following file:

```
case1, a, b, c, ...
case2, x, y, z, ...
case9, aa, b, cc, ..
case22, 1,2,3, ...
```

I would use Java 8's `Stream` to read file line by line and only pick up those lines of file that contains elements of `cases` as declared above. The Stream will read the file line by line, pick up a line, send it to another method to check if the line contain any of the test cases that is in `cases` list, if yes then it returns true and `Stream` will save that line in the `readCases` list. If the line don't contain any of the test cases, then it is skipped by Stream. See below sample code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFileStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //cases that you picked from table
        List<String> cases = Arrays.asList("case1", "case9");

        //open stream to file, please change directory and filename
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\test_java", "filterfile.txt"));

        //loop through stream line by line, pick up those that match
        List<String> readCases = lines.filter(line -> containsAll(line, cases)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        lines.close();
        System.out.println(readCases);
    }

    //this is a simple method that performs String's contains() for each
    //case in the list. 
    public static boolean containsAll(String line, List<String> cases) {
        for (String s : cases) {
            if (line.contains(s)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output for the above input is:

```
[case1, a, b, c, ..., case9, aa, b, cc, ..]
```